# Upload text file to database

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I have got text file that have next structure:

```
id=123
name=value
year=2013
```

Where first part (id, name, year) is name of column, and the last part - the data that I need to past in column. I have not any idea how to do it.
 1. I am reading files line by line
 2. ??

I have only stupid idea to replace '=' with query and to try run it. But it's look like bad idea...

Also I need to check if the data present in DB.

Comment: where did you search for this? I'm wondering, because it took me about 15 seconds to find for instance [this](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html).. Would that help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your text file
2. Read it line by line
3. Update DB

### How I would do it

- Upload text file
- Create a `List` of objects that has those values and has implemented
  [validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/).
- [Read every line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and every three lines `try` to construct a valid
  object of that type in case of errors since I'd had to use regex or something similar to distinguish key from value.
- Update database via LINQ2SQL with using my list of objects